# Bootstrap 4 TypeScript Type Definition fails to compile - Cannot find module 'popper.js'

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, bootstrap-4, popper.js, type-definition

I am attempting to set up a TypeScript project and get bootstrap 4 working along with **Popper**, **jQuery**, and **Knockout** in Visual Studio Code.

I installed the knockout, jquery and bootstrap type definitions,

```
npm install -–save @types/knockout
npm install -–save @types/jquery
npm install --save @types/bootstrap
```

referenced the JS files in a require.js config

```
declare var require: any;
require.config({
    paths: {
        "knockout": "externals/knockout-3.5.0",
        "jquery": "externals/jquery-3.3.1.min",
        "popper.js": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js",
        "bootstrap": "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    }
})
```

my `tsconfig.json` is this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": { 
            "*": ["types/*"] 
        },
        "outDir": "./built/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "files":[
        "src/require-config.ts",
        "src/hello.ts"
    ]
}
```

I go to compile the project and I get the following error:

```
node_modules/@types/bootstrap/index.d.ts:9:25 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'popper.js'.

9 import * as Popper from "popper.js";
                          ~~~~~~~~~~~

Found 1 error.

The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
```

It appears my Bootstrap type definition file fails compilation as it cannot find the popper.js module.

The popper.js module *is* in my @types folder

```
node_modules
 |-@types
 |  |- bootstrap
 |     |-index.d.ts (this is failing)
 |- popper.js
    |- index.d.ts (popper.js type definition)
```

How do I tell the TypeScript compiler that the popper.js that the bootstrap type definition is looking for is located higher up in the hierarchy?

I haven't been able to find any answers even close to this. So, either I have stumbled across a bug no one else has ever run into (unlikely), or being new to Typescript, I have improperly set up my environment and missed a very basic setup step that everyone else gets and thus no one has ever had to ask (very likely).

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two options for you:

- remove the `"module": "amd"` configuration option OR
- add the `"moduleResolution": "node"` option.

The second option looks like this:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
"module": "amd",
```

Why do these options work?

In short, when we use `amd` modules, the default module resolution strategy is **Classic** as opposed to **Node**. The important difference between the two is that *the Node strategy recognizes directory names as modules whereas the Classic strategy does not.*

There is more information on [module resolution strategies here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#module-resolution-strategies).

Comment: :/ Figure it was something like that. Easy win. Thanks.

Comment: Which option did you choose?

Comment: The second option works. Appreciate the explanation... always be learning.

Comment: Greate answer,. It helped me with my bootstrap 4.3.1 popper.js 1.11 problem. I added moduleResolution: node and the compile error went away.

Comment: moduleResolution:node worked on BS 4.3 & popper 1.11 - something that's been working for months and just started failing (VS2019). It's so frustrating when things are working and then they're not :(. Thanks for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first result that came up for me when I had the issue.

[This Github comment](https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core/issues/769#issuecomment-496985974) helped me.

> This library requires DOM library (browser environment)
>
> You should add dom as well as 'es2017' to compilerOptions.lib in tsconfig.json.

I only added `"lib": [ "DOM" ]` to my `tsconfig.json` to make it work for me and I'm still targeting `es5`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me; the bootstrap definition imports popper but popper definitions dont exist in the normal @types folder ... changing the library wont make any difference to that surely